# entity type attribute in every datomic entity

Tags: clojure, datomic

Is it idiomatic to tag every entity in Datomic database, with a universal "type attribute", i.e. `:entity/type`? Or it is better not to do it, and derive type from combination of attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [tutorial](http://docs.datomic.com/tutorial.html) they use namespace keywords for all their attributes like this:

```clj
:community/name 
:neighborhood/name
:district/name
```

to avoid name collisions. I've used this strategy without problems and it seems to be the idiomatic way. When you want to know if an entity is a `community` you ask for some mandatory attribute like `:community/name` and check if it is there.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Will try to model it without tags, and rely only on attributes and their values.